# 'Invalid Python SDK' error right after creating a new project in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

### Background

Some time ago I seriously crashed my Windows computer while using PyCharm - I remember some errors about memory and then a hard crash with no blue screen - just black with some thin vertical lines and reboot to Windows installation / fixing screen. Since then, I had this problem, with no way I found online to fix this.

Edit : Apparently, this has nothing to do with the problem.

### The problem

Whenever I open a project, or create a new one, an error appears with the Invalid Python SDK error message.

---

```
**Invalid Python SDK**
Cannot set up a Python SDKat Python 3.9 (%projectName%) (%projectPath%).The SDK seems to be invalid.
```

---

Also, this is what the [work environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJdJe.png) looks like the moment I close this message. In the Project window, the `venv` directory (and every directory under it) is marked as an Exclusion, and in the code, the `print(f'Hi, {name}')` function is marked as an unresolved reference error shown below. The program, however, executes flawlessly.

[image: unresolved reference error]

What's more, when I go to Python Interpreter settings at `File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter` there's a yellow bar on the bottom which says:

> Non-zero exit code (4).

which after some time says:

> Python packaging tools not found.

Upon installing, nothing changes, and I can't add packages from this screen (the '+' button is greyed out):

[image: greyed out]

When I try to check Python interpreter paths, there are no paths shown, and I don't know what that means:

[image: no paths]

**In short**, all of the default Python functions like print are marked as errors, even though they work when executed. This makes coding *extremely* confusing, as I can't quickly distinguish between real errors and 'errors'.

### The search for solution

Normally this would be a problem with interpreter set-up or path, but I've tried most of the methods proposed in other answers to similar questions. To name a few :

- PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code
- 'Cannot setup a Python SDK' in PyCharm project using virtualenv after OS reinstallation
- Why do I get an 'SDK seems invalid' error when setting up my Project Interpreter in PyCharm?
- Invalid Python SDK Error while using python 3.4 on PyCharm
- Invalid Python SDK when setting a venv

There were supposed to be links, but I don't have enough reputation on Stack Overflow to post them with the questions. These, however, can be easily looked up in Google, all of them are posted to Stack Overflow.

### What I tried

I should mention that the first things I tried were removing and installing PyCharm, all user configurations and Python itself as well. I installed Python from the official site, and from the PyCharm application, both methods ended with the same result.

1. `File -> Invalidate Caches... -> Invalidate and restart.` Didn't work.
2. Checking file interpreter in `Edit Configurations`. Don't know what to make of it. The result:

[image: The result.]

3. Refreshing the interpreter paths. Even now, the paths yield no results.

[image: no results]

4. Removing the interpreter and adding it again. No result.
5. Deleting the `.idea` folder. No result.
6. Deleting PyCharm user preferences under `%homepath%/.PyCharm50`. I don't have that folder though.
7. Switching interpreter back and forth. No result.
8. Creating a new interpreter in a different location. No result.
9. Marking project directory as root `ProjectName -> Mark Directory as -> Sources Root` and unmarking other directories as Excluded. No result.
10. Using no interpreter. Yeah, it doesn't mark non-errors as errors anymore. But the code doesn't work. That's not a solution for me.
11. Checking if `venv/pyvenv.cfg` has paths set correctly. These look fine to me.

[image: fine]

12. Checking Windows environment variables - Path variable. It was in the user section, but wasn't in the system section. I added it, restarted but still no result.
13. Changing account name in Windows. My account name was 'username' and that's how my User folder is called `C:\Users\username', but I later connected it to Microsoft account and my user name is now User Name with a space and I can't really change it. My folder stayed the same. Not sure if I can fix it that way.

To the two last things I tried I should also add that I changed my Windows username from 'username' to 'user name' with a space, but that wasn't until recently.

I'm attaching the `idea.log` [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uUMDFcGQmWqhZBkJGI6BFhmmxhcHolnn/view?usp=sharing) for you to check. I replaced my real username with 'User Name' to highlight the existence of a space.

Comment: +1 for a lot of effort put into question! I have no idea what's going on, but your log file complains a lot about failing to convert some characters, and I see that your path is `C:\Users\aweg2\Desktop\Praca inżynierska\MRC\venv\Scripts\python.exe`. Probably won't do much, but maybe try to get rid of non ASCII characters from the path?

Comment: Oh. My... that was the answer. Thank you, psarka. It works when there are no non-ASCII characters in path. Feel free to post it as an answer, although I'm not sure if this is how PyCharm should work. I seems to me like it *should* be able to handle that... Maybe I should install something more? Cheers

Comment: It's apparently a know [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50988) Good catch @psarka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, that was a lucky one! I'm thus posting my comment as an answer:

The problem is caused by the non-ASCII characters in the path, and the solution is to remove them. As indicated by @TheLazyScripter this is a known issue.

Comment: Well, that is what one would call a "Bruh moment"...