# Python packaging tools not found by PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I was going to casually install a package with the built-in installer, but i could not, because of the following problem. Project > Python Interpreter plus sign is greyed out, and it says Python packaging tools not found. When I click on 'install packaging tools' I get the command output you can see in the picture: Chinese signs and meaningless stuff.

Command output:

[image: command output]

It says that I could try a command in the terminal which when I try I get the error:

> C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Pip installed, updated. Python at stock directory. Up to date PyCharm Community.

Any ideas? So frustrating, I haven't seen anyone with this problem but I've been searching for a solution for a while.
**Just to be clear: I ended up installing the package with pip from terminal but the IDE does not recognize it at importing.**

I tried deleting all interpreters, reinstalling PyCharm and reinstalling Python, plus reinstalling pip.

Comment: Maybe [one of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+%22Python+packaging+tools+not+found%22) going by the error message? You don't say what your operating system is.

Comment: Another common cause [is shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69691677) that might explain the chinese characters. So it seems you are having several issues at the same time, try solving each one separately, and it's fundamental in these cases to say what your operating system is.

Comment: Actually I've read all of the available posts here with the same title but none helped... nobody had the same command output. btw it's windows but i thought it'd be obvious from the directory name mentioned. Sorry then.

Comment: I read the long post about where the solution was removing ascii characters from the path, but I don't have one of those so it can't be an issue.

Comment: See [the screenshots here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34116833) a non-ascii character might look like a regular character so you'll likely have to clean that string just to make sure. You could have inadvertently copy-pasted something or a 3rd party program altered your path variable introducing illegal characters.

Comment: And another thing: Delete that venv, make a fresh Python installation in a directory you control and create a venv using that fresh interpreter. Put the venv outside your project directory to not further complicate things. Here's another culprit for you: `"C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"` I think that's the default Python installation that comes with Windows? If so it's not suitable for development, [download from here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) install outside of `user/appdata` and start over, that should be enough.

Comment: Still nothing sadly. I made a fresh install for python to user\program files and a independent venv to python directory and a new project using this venv but still nothing. Still no packaging tools found and still chinese characters. Driving me mad

Comment: Okay so there's an update. I installed conda, which i can browse installed packages with. So there must be an interpreter problem with venv. However, I still can't use the package I'd like to. After installing it from terminal with pip install colorgram.py, it still doesn't exist in the packag list in the preferences, and it doesn't recognize it when i'm trying to import it to .py

Comment: At this point your question can no longer be answered. You're not showing how and where you are installing things, or how your settings are configured exactly. Personally I wouldn't try conda before getting a barebones PyCharm working with a basic venv. You can post your logs at [the JetBrains bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20PyCharm) but be mindful you have to follow the devs exact instructions on what to do there.